# Weird behaviour of DownloadFileAsync (WebClient)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script for downloading/uploading files to FTP. It worked just fine on Unity 2018.1.9f1, but recently I updated Unity to 2018.4.5f1 and DownloadFileAsyn got broken. It writes an empty file with error "Server returned an error: 550  No such file or directory". The file is there, the permissions are correct(I'm sure of it, because my UploadFile method still works fine). I wrote a new method using FtpWebRequest(same credentials, file path etc.), and guess what - it works fine too! But WebClient download is broken.

My DownloadFileAsync method:

```
    public void DownloadFile(string FilePath)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download Path: " + FilePath);

        WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(OnFileDownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(OnFileDownloadCompleted);

        client.QueryString.Add("filename", FilePath);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + FilePath);
    }
```

My new download method using FtpWebRequest(it works, but i prefer WebClient):

```
public void DownloadFileNew(string FilePath)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(god.persPath + "/" + FilePath))
    {
        ftpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

And finally UploadFile method using WebClient that still works fine:

```
public void UploadFile(string FilePath)
{
    FilePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + FilePath;
    Debug.Log("Upload Path: " + FilePath);

    WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(FTPHost + new FileInfo(FilePath).Name);

    client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(OnFileUploadProgressChanged);
    client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(OnFileUploadCompleted);
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);

    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", FilePath);
}
```

Comment: If you found a working solution please don't post it as updates to the question but rather add it as an answer. This way people A) can see you already found a solution and B) people with the same problem can find your question and solution

Comment: btw you should rather use `Path.Combine` instead of using `+ "/" +` for concatenating system paths

Comment: Thanks for advise! As for the answer instead of updates - i'll do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

```
client.QueryString.Add("filename", FilePath);
```

Somehow, the problem is in that line. I used it to identify what file I downloaded in `OnFileDownloadCompleted`.

`userToken` seems like a better option for this.

Comment: is the file name url safe file names can contain dot were as url can not.